# cocos2d swift how to present a scene?

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone

Just started with coco2d/swift and am having trouble presenting a scene.  I created a new one in spritebuilder, published it, and am loading it with CCReader as a scene.  When I try to present it, it won't present.

```
class MainScene: CCNode {

    override init(){
        super.init()
        let mainMenu = CCBReader.loadAsScene("ccbResources/MainMenu");
        CCDirector.presentScene(mainMenu)
    }
}
```

I get a build error saying:

> "cannot invoke presentScene with an argument list of type CCScene".

So I can't really find any examples of this working for me or how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Only once you can use presentScene, then try replaceScene

```
class GameScene: CCScene {
    class func scene() -> GameScene
    {
        return GameScene()
    }

    override init()
    {
        super.init()

    }
}

class MainScene: CCScene {
    class func scene() -> MainScene
    {
        return MainScene()
    }

    override init()
    {
        super.init()

        //to replace scene
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(GameScene.scene())
    }
}
```